# 2 stage least squares

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I am looking into the effect of immigration on crime (using random effects panel data). there are 2 problems which 2 stage least squares should help with, firstly the endogeneity of immigration (as patterns are likely related to city specifics in the error term) and secondly to search for a secondary effect of immigration (as immigration may affect unemployment which then effects crime). I understand an instrumental variable must firstly be used which is correlated with immigration but not crime, for which I am using immigration for t-10, and for the second problem the instrument must be related to immigration but not unemployment, again the same instrument could be used. Will both these problems be solved in a 2SLS with the one instrument of previous immigration?

Comment: There are some serious problems with using lagged variables. In your case, your instrument would "solve" neither of the two issues you mention. If you're worried about city specifics affecting immigration and crime rates, this will also apply to immigration in t-10, hence your instrument does not meet the requirements. Your question about secondary effects raises a similar concern. But (for me) raises an additional question: I don't  understand what you'd consider the "primary" effect you want to test for/reject. Is it "migrants commit crimes" or "people commit crimes if migrants are there"